# C# edm datagridview showing foreign keys as an additional column that is not in the SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server

My SQL Server table only has 10 columns, and from running the `select * from table` command in SQL, I can see there's only 10 columns. However, when I use it in edm in C# windows form datagrid view, it shows 13 columns, the additional 4 columns I suspect from the foreign keys:

[SQL Table View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7Mu4.jpg)

The codes I used:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SA45Team02bLibraryEntities context;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            context = new SA45Team02bLibraryEntities();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = (from x in context.IssueTransactions select x).ToList();
        }
    }
```

The following is what appears on the datagridview:

[datagridviewtable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khfoh.jpg)

The front of the table is the same as what was in the SQL Server table view, but additional 4 columns which corresponds to the number of foreign key I have on that table. Same number of extra columns appear corresponding to the number of foreign key I have on other tables as well.

Have anyone encountered this before and is there any ways to solve this issue other than selecting only the columns I want to show manually?

Comment: I doubt that here's a way to avoid this other than using a projection into an anonymous type. ex:`context.IssueTransactions.Select(x =. new { x.a, x.b, ...})`

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about DataGridView, just set

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false
```

Then make sure DataPropertyName matches the column name of your data source.

Otherwise like @ESG said, use anonymous type when you do the select.